# Overriding onBackPressed() not working

Tags: android, onbackpressed

In my app I want to allow the user to insert some data which later appears in a list. This aspect is organized as follows:
From the Main Activity, the user can press a button which opens the Editor Activity. Here it's possible to construct the data. Pressing the confirm button, the built data are showed in another activity (New Element Activity), in a list. 
Well, if the user goes back through the designated button from New Element Activity to Main Activity I want the list to be cancelled, while now, when adding a new element, the former is still there (that's because the array with the data was initialized before onCreate() method - I don't want to change it). I tried to override the onBackPressed() method, but it didn't work. Suggestions?

Here's my code - the onBackPressed() method.

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
    data.clear();
    Log.d("onBackPressed", "called");
}
```

Clicking the back button just returns to the previous activity. The overridden method doesn't get called. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend you read **[how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**, next **[how to create Minimal, Complete and Verifable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** and quickly edit your question accordingly before it gets downvoted and burried.

Comment: What does it mean "it didn't work"? Be more specific. Also, provide source code of the relevant parts that don't work and as much **relevant** information as possible (for example, logs).

Comment: Ok, I just edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class));

}
```